# How to detect if object stored in pointer is deleted?

Tags: c++

I have pointers in a module (Let's call module A) to store all objects (in module B) I want to access. It works fine.

When dynamic creation/deletion function is added for those objects (in module B). Creation is fine while deletion gives problems that my pointers are not valid any more.

Is there any easy way for check if the object pointed by pointers are still valid? (I can think of to add functions in destructor of objects in Module B to notify module A for updates, but this is not that easy)

Answer (score 3):

No. You have to *manage* the lifetime of the object somehow.

Fortunately, the C++ standard library gives us tools to do this: use `std::shared_ptr` for pointers that can share ownership of an object and `std::weak_ptr` for pointers that point at something managed by shared pointers but do not participate in the ownership sharing scheme themselves.

(also, use `std::unique_ptr` when that is appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

No, in general there is no way to test if a (raw) pointer points to a valid object or not.

Only case where you know a pointer doesn't point to a valid object for sure is if it's value is null. So, if you always set a pointer to null after deleting the pointed object, then you can check the validity by testing nullness. Of course, this quickly becomes unbearable if you ever make copies of the pointer.

It's much easier to guarantee the validity by using smart pointers. Objects pointed by only `shared_ptr` or only `unique_ptr` will never be deleted as long as you're pointing at it. Unless the object is silly and calls `delete this`.